# How choose a framework to develop web application like CRM?

Tags: frameworks, backend

I want to develop a web application like CRM (Customer Relationship management) but I don't know  if I will choose spring boot to develop the back-end or Django with Python.

What are the parameters we need to consider while choosing back-end technology?

Anyone could help me, please.

Comment: This is a very broad question and subject to personal opinion. I think you need to be specific about what you are looking for so that people can give you advice. What is your expertise and experience level? What are you looking for in a develop tool, e.g. power, ease of use, scalability, popularity, support, speed, storage, plug ins/components. What key tech features do you really need from your tech stack? Who are the target market, mobile users, small business etc Otherwise you will just get rants from people who love tech for reasons that may not matter or be relevant to you.

Comment: Thank's for your reply, I want to develop reporting web application, for data visualisation, I will display in the Dashboard all of the data that I will have stored in RDBMS in diagram or another one graphics, with filters, and may notify all the users with certain condition in the data, my expertise in web applciation it's spring boot, java ee with struts, the application has few users perhaps 5 juste for data visualisation, and notification but I should excute python scripts that will start a scanning process to recover data and stor them in my RDBMS.

Comment: Hi Gaya, I can't really answer your question as it is not my sphere, however I am trying to help you to get your issue raised correctly so the right people will read it. I would suggest editing the issue above with the extra information. I would also add some more specific tags to it, certainly Django and Python, Java etc. That way the right people should see it. Hope that helps.